# Is the URL's hash available on the server with Node.js?

Tags: node.js

Today, I fell upon this link : [Node API's doc for 'url'](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.1/api/url.html).

I saw that the `hash` part is included in the documentation. But isn't this part **not** available on the server? That's what I always thought.

Any explanation? What did I get wrong?

Comment: It could be sent server-to-server, just not from a browser.

Comment: also note that is the documentation for node.js v0.3.1 which is quite old try looking at the more current http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.8/api/url.html which does in fact handle the hash part of a url

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, there will not be a hash in the URL sent from the client to the server as part of the HTTP request.

But that's not the only case where Node would need to manipulate URLs. You could well be writing server-side code to generate a URL that will be inserted into the HTML sent back to the client (e.g., you might have a list of hyperlinks, and be generating the URLs for those hyperlinks).

For that reason, it makes sense for Node's URL API to be complete, even if one part of the URL will be missing in one common use case.

Comment: Your answer is better, I'm marking it as best answer :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, the http client removes it before it queries the server for the page, so the server never has access to it.